# Uncaught TypeError: socket.send is not a function

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста,нужна горячая помощь!

```
function sendMessage(){
    socket = document.body.getAttribute("Socket");
    login = document.getElementById("Conversation").getAttribute("login");
    content_area = document.getElementById("Message").value;
    message = {
        user_name:login,
        date:new Date(),
        content:content_area
    }

    json = JSON.stringify(message);

    socket.send(json); 
    этот вызов выдает
    //Uncaught TypeError: socket.send is not a function 

}
```

Скрин лога
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `console.log(typeof socket, socket);`

Comment: @Igor добавил скрин

Comment: Что вы недоговариваете? `getAttribute` вернет или строку или `null`. Как можно к этому применить метод `send()`?

Comment: @Deonis вот же блин,я же джавист,а мы в атрибуты запихаем объекты и не только.Как мне в javascript сохранить созданный сокет,чтобы я мог обращаться к нему позже?

Comment: @Deonis Спасибо огромное за помощь.Использовал понятие "свойство" для того,чтобы сохранить объект для дальнейшего использования!А про атрибуты в js  понял!

Comment: Гора с плеч ))) Т.к. ваш вопрос, честно говоря, слегка поставил в тупик и сидел думал, с какой бы стороны начать, чтобы коротко и понятно донести до вас суть. ))

Comment: мне следовало обратить внимание на номера строк на изображении консоли